# Does Tanuki wrapper software work with a bootclasspath jar that does instrumentation?

Tags: java, wrapper, instrumentation, terracotta

We are using AS3 and Java and the SmartFox Server and have used the Tanuki wrapper on linux successfully for several months.  However now we are trying to add Terracotta to our project.  Terracotta provides clustering and as discussed in these links, uses Java instrumentation.

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=16741#16741

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7524

Can anyone please tell me if Tanuki should work with instrumentation and -Xbootclasspath/p:my-terracotta-boot-file-here.jar - and if so, things I can do to find out why it is not seeming to work when I try it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a few days research and found that yes, this wrapper software does work with instrumentation.

1) I emailed Tanuki and they confirmed they have plenty of clients that use their product with instrumentation.
2) I had to fix several bugs but I finally got it working myself.  Here are the things I had to watch out for:
  -need to match java version and boot jar, and be sure you're using the right java directory
  -need to ensure config files are set up right, including having a public class and full package name, and separate root nodes per shared/clustered variable

Hope this helps someone else.